# get data from mongodb document by month

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a user document and have createdAt, so what should I do in the condition in order to get the data by month?

the createdAt value look like this

```
2016-10-08T16:21:40.935Z
Account.find({'what to pass here?'}, function(err,response){
        if(!err){
            console.log(response)
        }
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean `by month`? you want records from specific date?

Comment: do u want records in specific date range or u want them grouped by month??

Comment: @A.B. by month, like I get month of this month, then pass into it, but what should it be? do I need $gte or $lt to specify a range? I need need monthly data.

Comment: `{"createdAt": {'$gte': new Date('2016-10-01'), '$lt': new Date('2016-10-31')}}` try putting this...

Comment: @A.B. how do i know the date of the first day of this month? and the range of says Sept, August etc?

Comment: @Maria Jane Please see my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Account.find({
  "createdAt": {
    "$lte": "2016-10-08T16:21:40.935Z"
  }
}, function(err, response) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(response)
  }
});
```

You can also define range to get specific data

```
Account.find({
  "createdAt": {
     "$gte": "2016-10-06T16:21:40.935Z",
    "$lte": "2016-10-08T16:21:40.935Z"
  }
}, function(err, response) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(response)
  }
});
```

Comment: what is this? it will get all the data, hmm i think i must specified a range, like $gte : 1-10-2016 which is the first day of this month.

Comment: Yes you can define also range to get the records

Comment: how to get the range in node.js? I can't just hardcode it.

Comment: You no need to do hard code just give your range if you know

Comment: you can also use momentjs to get  last month or next month time with given time

Comment: if I want to build a dashboard, how do I set the date range in your opinion?

Comment: As I mentioned in above comment, if you know the createdAt or current date then you can use momentjs to get last or next month from current date
with `add` or `subract` method http://momentjs.com/docs/# and use that range in your query

Answer (score 3):

Try putting this condition...

`{"createdAt": {'$gte': new Date('2016-10-01'), '$lt': new Date('2016-10-31')}}`

If you want these two dates to be generated dynamically using just a month number and year. Put the below code.

```
const month = 10;
const year = 2016;
const fromDate = new Date(year, month, 1);
const toDate = new Date(fromDate.getFullYear(), fromDate.getMonth() + 1, 0);

const condition = {"createdAt": {'$gte': date, '$lte': lastDay}};

Account.find(condition, function(err, response){
    if (!err){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: the user will not able to see the data of days that haven't happens. like there will be no data for tomorrow or days after today, why use lastDay?

Comment: lastDay is the last day of that particular month... u wanted the data between first and last day of month right?

Comment: no. will u have the data of tomorrow in a sales report? no right?

Comment: My answer was in case if u wanted data for previous month or may be some other month... It would give u the data for any month u have given. Not just current month.